# How to fix "Telephony linked to a SIM identity (e.g., wifi calling linked to a carrier account)" while uploading my app on playstore

Tags: android, mobile

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pd75.png)]
Please help me to fix this

changing data safety form didn't work